# How to use loc on to filter on multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use loc to filter on multiple cities for the column `Name`

I've tried filtering using several column names:

```
popdemo_df.loc[popdemo_df['Name'] == 'Richmond city', ['Name'] == Landsdowne']
```

I get the following error:

False, unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: `popdemo_df.loc[(popdemo_df['Name'] == 'Richmond city') | (popdemo_df['Name'] == 'Landsdowne')]`

Answer (score 3):

In order to combine [Boolean indices](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), you need to surround them with parentheses and use the bitwise operators `&`, `|`, or `~`, like so:

```
# Selects rows where either condition is met
popdemo_df.loc[(popdemo_df['Name'] == 'Richmond city') | (popdemo_df['Name'] == 'Landsdowne')]
```

You can do the same with [`Series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) as well:

```
popdemo_df.loc[popdemo_df['Name'].isin(['Richmond city', 'Landsdowne'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isin`:

```
popdemo_df.loc[popdemo_df['Name'].isin(['Richmond city','Landsdowne'])]
```

Comment: While this is the way to do this, I just want to point out to OP that your problem wasn't not using `isin`, your problem was using a comma between dataframe masks and not an pipe (|). As well as calling `['Name']` without a dataframe.

Comment: you mean |? it would be impossible for ['Name'] to be two unique values at once

Answer (score 0):

Commas are used to separate rows and columns inside `df.loc` brackets. To combine conditionals, you can use `&` for `and`, `|` for `or` and `~` for `not`.

Try this instead:

```
popdemo_df.loc[:, popdemo_df['Name'] == 'Richmond city' | popdemo_df['Name'] == 'Landsdowne']
```